# How to load TrustStore file from jar?

Tags: web-services, security, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-web-start

I'm consuming a web service secured with username authentification with symmetric keys via a [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) client. The problem is that my `TrustStore` is hard coded in the WSIT file, so authenfication fails with `FileNotFoundException`.

```
  <wsp:All>
       <sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
            <sc:CallbackHandler default="h" name="usernameHandler"/>
            <sc:CallbackHandler default="kiko" name="passwordHandler"/>
       </sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration>
       <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private"
           location="C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks"
           type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="xws-security-server"/>
  </wsp:All>
```

How can I embed the truststore with the application and load it from the jar? Thanks.

**Edit 1**

this is the exception in the jws client :

```
30 juin 2012 09:44:01 [com.sun.xml.ws.policy.parser.PolicyConfigParser] parse
INFO: WSP5018: Loaded WSIT configuration from file: jar:http://server_url.net:8080/___JWSappclient/___app/realm_consumer/realm_consumerClient/realm_consumer.jar!/META-INF/wsit-client.xml.
30 juin 2012 09:44:04 com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler initTrustStore
GRAVE: WSS1509: Failed to initialize Trust store
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:909)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.<init>(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:822)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.SecurityTubeFactory.createTube(SecurityTubeFactory.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
at realm_consumer.Cw_Service.getCwPort(Cw_Service.java:72)
at realm_consumer.Ws.hmd(Ws.java:24)
at Gui.Gui.jButton1ActionPerformed(Gui.java:80)
at Gui.Gui.access$000(Gui.java:14)
at Gui.Gui$1.actionPerformed(Gui.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
30 juin 2012 09:44:04 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube configureClientHandler
GRAVE: WSSTUBE0027: Error in configuring Client Security Callback Handler.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:919)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.<init>(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:822)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.SecurityTubeFactory.createTube(SecurityTubeFactory.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
at realm_consumer.Cw_Service.getCwPort(Cw_Service.java:72)
at realm_consumer.Ws.hmd(Ws.java:24)
at Gui.Gui.jButton1ActionPerformed(Gui.java:80)
at Gui.Gui.access$000(Gui.java:14)
at Gui.Gui$1.actionPerformed(Gui.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:909)
... 56 more
30 juin 2012 09:44:04 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube <init>
GRAVE: WSSTUBE0023: Error in creating new instance of SecurityClientTube
java.lang.RuntimeException: WSSTUBE0027: Error in configuring Client Security Callback Handler.
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:826)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.SecurityTubeFactory.createTube(SecurityTubeFactory.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
at realm_consumer.Cw_Service.getCwPort(Cw_Service.java:72)
at realm_consumer.Ws.hmd(Ws.java:24)
at Gui.Gui.jButton1ActionPerformed(Gui.java:80)
at Gui.Gui.access$000(Gui.java:14)
at Gui.Gui$1.actionPerformed(Gui.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:919)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.<init>(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:822)
... 54 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:909)
... 56 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: WSSTUBE0023: Error in creating new instance of SecurityClientTube
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:185)
at com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.SecurityTubeFactory.createTube(SecurityTubeFactory.java:285)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:84)
at com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:228)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:205)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:85)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:330)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:312)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
at realm_consumer.Cw_Service.getCwPort(Cw_Service.java:72)
at realm_consumer.Ws.hmd(Ws.java:24)
at Gui.Gui.jButton1ActionPerformed(Gui.java:80)
at Gui.Gui.access$000(Gui.java:14)
at Gui.Gui$1.actionPerformed(Gui.java:43)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: WSSTUBE0027: Error in configuring Client Security Callback Handler.
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:826)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:180)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:919)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.<init>(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:340)
at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.configureClientHandler(SecurityClientTube.java:822)
... 54 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain_1\config\cacerts.jks (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler.initTrustStore(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:909)
```

I'm using glassfish 3.1.1 and metro/jax-ws . THe problem is that the path is hard coded in the xml file and I have to load it from the jar within the client .

Comment: To help me understand what you are trying to do, what web server are you using?  Are you using Tomcat or some other J2EE?  Also please forgive my next question, but where is this WSIT file located, on the server?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: the path in the configuration file and the question tag suggest Glassfish 3. This is far from an ancient J2EE server, it's a modern Java EE server.

Comment: @isoman Can you show us where you are getting the FileNotFoundException?  Is it possible that the file not found exception is for the cacerts.jks file on the server?  Is the location path correct for this file?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, I you are most likely correct.  I should have noticed Glassfish in the path.

Comment: The exception is throwed in the client when I try to acces a protected webservcice method . Please see Edit 1

Comment: @isoman I need to try to replicate this, but since the client appears to read the location from the server can this value be an http reference to the file on the web server?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn : I used netbeans to generate the webservice client from a remote server . You can modify the xml in your client's project locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by putting cacert.jks under source/Meta-inf pakage and changing the path in the WSIT file manually. The XML looks like:

```
 <wsp:All>
       <sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration wspp:visibility="private">
            <sc:CallbackHandler default="h" name="usernameHandler"/>
            <sc:CallbackHandler default="kiko" name="passwordHandler"/>
       </sc:CallbackHandlerConfiguration>
       <sc:TrustStore wspp:visibility="private"
           location="cacerts.jks"
           type="JKS" storepass="changeit" peeralias="xws-security-server"/>
  </wsp:All>
```

Comment: I recomment that you select your answer as the best for your issue.

Comment: I tried but i got a message : you can accept your own answer in x hours

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article that talks about how to reference a DTD file contained in a jar file: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233092

May not apply.

Comment: I solved it , I putted the file under meta-inf package and changed the path  to  location="cacerts.jks".

Comment: Great!  Can you post the final XML for others to see.  I take it that you mean meta-inf package in your Eclipse project?

Comment: @isoman  May I recommend that you add your own answer with your solution and then accept it to close out this issue?